# React Native - Direct user back to login if current user token is invalid?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have this code that authenticates the user session by taking their token and sending it to AWS-amplify to ensure their token hasn't timed out and it's a valid user

```
import {Auth} from 'aws-amplify';

export async function getAccessToken() {
    try {
        // const currentUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
        // console.log(currentUser);

        return await Auth
            .currentSession()
            .then(res => {
                let accessToken = res.getAccessToken();
                let jwt = accessToken.getJwtToken();
                // You can print them to see the full objects
                // console.log(`myAccessToken: ${JSON.stringify(accessToken)}`);
                // console.log(`myJwt: ${JSON.stringify(jwt)}`);
                return jwt
            });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

This gets called when make ANY endpoint call, because I want to ensure the user has been validated by aws-amplify. So for example I might have some code that does something like

```
  function getSomething() {
    getAccessToken().then(token => {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      };


      axios
        .get(<url>, config)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data)
          setData(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    });;
  };
```

So every endpoint call of my app requires the access token and if it's not authenticated properly the backend will shoot back a 401. If 401 is received I want to automatically bounce users back to login for any and all screens (except login of course)

for navigation I'm using

```
const NavigatorTab = ({navigation}) => {
```

and just setting the `navigation` parameter.

Comment: What library are you using for navigation?

Comment: jwt have 3 component. header.body.signature. you need to split the jwt by "." dot, get the middle one. And then decrypt it with base64. Now you can read the exp timestamp, simply compare it with current timestamp and if its expired redirect it to login or hit the refresh token if you have any.  check this => https://jwt.io try paste your jwt there